# bind-address in my.ini of MYSQL

Tags: mysql, remote-access

i am trying to access my mysql database from another pc...the another pc can be from anywhere... so i heard about bind-adress in my.ini file.
but i dont know anything about it.

i have created user with all permissions along with uername and password using workbench.
i have assigned a static ip for my pc.
i have created inbound and outbound port rules in firewall setting.for port number 3306
and now when i tried the connection using online mysql connection tool. but it gives me error called Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip address' (13)

please tell me, what exactly i need to write in the value of bind-address? 0.0.0.0 or the static ip address of my pc? (MY PC is working as a server pc)

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is sufficient unless you really know what you're doing. Most probably you have a user permissions problem rather than a connectivity problem.

Comment: will you please explain?

Comment: coz, the online tool from which i am testing my remote connection, their ip address is, 38.113.1.97, so i have added the user with this ip address using the following command:  CREATE USER 'varsha'@'38.113.1.97' IDENTIFIED BY '1236';>>>>>>and also given access to it by using command: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO '
varsha
'@'38.113.1.97';

Comment: So, whats wrong with the user permissions?

Comment: I think i am facing problem because of my ip address. let say when i run command ipconfig, it gives me the ip address... 192.168.#.#; but someone said me that i should use the WAN ip address...so i logged in to the router setting, and in the checked the ip address. the above ip address was given by my router. so, should i use the ip address, given by my router(stated in the WAN information)???? (Sorry, actually i am new to this)